# Can squibs give birth to normal wizards?

Tags: harry-potter

I was just wondering about squibs in Harry Potter.  I can't remember if they can give birth to normal wizards, does anyone know?

Comment: squibs are generally encouraged to live among muggles, this leads me to believe they also tend to have non-wizard children. but still the potential for muggle-born wizard children.

Answer (score 6):

If non-wizards can have wizard children (look at Hermione) then why would squibs be any different? They're just muggle children born from wizard parents.

Comment: i think the intent of the question is based on, would a squib act like a muggle parent with a chance of a magical child, or like a wizard parent with a almost guarantied magical child.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information about the origins of magic on the potterverse as to answer that question, is there?

Comment: probably not but she could have done an interview and answered this question.